# No entries in SQLite databases on rooted Android

Tags: android, smartphone

I have recently rooted a `Samsung` Android 8.0 smartphone. I try to overserve changes in the stored `SQLite` database, i.e. the contacts2.db for contacts or chache4.db for Telegram messages. But it seems that these files never change. There occur only changes in the journaling files. Does this have anything to do with the root? There's also Xposed installed on the devices, but no modules are running.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think the reason for this is the WAL of the Databases.